# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'login_name' when using db_manager

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app that fetches bug information from a separate Bugzilla database.  My settings has two database entries, the non-default is for bugzilla.

I created a model that has the fields that I want from the Bugzilla profiles table (contains the users).

```
class Bugzilla_profiles(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'profiles'

    userid = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    login_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.login_name
```

When I try and fetch the data in a Django shell and try to read one of the fields, it says that there is no attribute.  I know it should be there, because if I just print the variable, it shows the right attribute via the unicode function.  I've tried accessing all 3 of the fields, and they all give the same error.

```
>>> from bugscrub.models import Bugzilla_profiles
>>> bz_assigned_to = Bugzilla_profiles.objects.db_manager('bugzilla').filter(userid=11)
>>> bz_assigned_to
[<Bugzilla_profiles: user@testdomain.com>]
>>> bz_assigned_to.login_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'login_name'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filter` returns a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) object, which does not contain your column names as attributes. You can use a [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead:

```
bz_assigned_to = Bugzilla_profiles.objects.db_manager('bugzilla').get(userid=11)  # changed filter to get
```

Or you can retrieve the object at the zeroeth position (for example) of the QuerySet:

```
bz_assigned_to[0].login_name  # the login_name attribute of the first 'row' in the QuerySet
```